# Where is the border between functional analysis and real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, terminology

I always thought that real analysis deals with analysis on the real line, eventually on the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$.

But why does someone have to label a course as real analysis when it is obviously an generalization and extension of the above to functions on more abstract spaces? Isn't it functional analysis then?

Take $L^p$ space, for example. How can it be in both real and functional analysis?

Comment: Course labels don't mean much. And it is certainly not the case that "different courses" are somehow mandated to have disjoint content. The "classification" of various mathematical ideas is itself highly contrived and irrelevant to the mathematics itself, although we (collectively) can make it operationally relevant by insisting in discussing things _only_ in those terms, and describing our activities according to whatever contrived classification scheme. But I don't think this is conducive to either understanding or good work.

Comment: Why are people now voting to close this?  If you have some problems with this post, let's discuss it in the [Close/Reopen chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/reopen-undelete-close-delete), since the effort to reopen (and recover) the question originated there. (Unless the reasons are so straightforward they can be conveyed in a comment.)

Answer (score 17):

> Let's take $L^p$ space for example: how can it be in both real and functional analysis?

If one uses "$L^p$" as notation for the set of functions that are Lebesgue integrable to the $p$th power, and proceeds to study the properties of individual functions in this set, this is **Real Analysis**. The mode of thinking here is not much different from studying the set $R[a,b]$ of Riemann-integrable functions on $[a,b]$.

If one introduces norm structure on the $L^p$  space,  induces topology with it, and proceeds to study  continuous linear functionals,  uniform convexity, etc, this is **Functional Analysis**. The focus shifts from the properties of individual functions to the structure of the space as a whole.

Comment: Indeed you are so right, but still the main topics in real/functional analysis are Banach and Hilbert spaces a.s.o. so i believe that one should label a course by its main focus, on what the course focuses at most or what distinguishes it from the others. In this case that is the generalization on function spaces and on anamorphic sets in general. Anyway the study of the real line or the Euclidean space is certainly not the focus of study of these courses, Wikipedia says the same.